# REMOTE_ADDR in PHP file called by XML based SOAP

Tags: php, xml, soap

I am using an XML based SOAP which calls a PHP file.

i am facing the following problem:
I want to read `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in a PHP File behind (called by) a SOAP (WSDL) but i just get the IP of the Server which hosts the SOAP. Instead i would like to see the IP of the user sending the SOAP CALL.
Is there a workaround?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you describe the setup in more detail? I.e. is "which hosts the soap" another server between the client and your php server?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the user's ip in your SOAP request. Obviously whoever is sending the request can send whatever IP he wnts to send.

Comment: yes, but isnt there a way to get the IP of the user? I makes no sense if i ask the user to send the IP as attribute himself.

Comment: The only IP you can access is the one of the system accessing your PHP script. If the user is accessing it directly, `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` will work, if the request is proxied throuh another system, only that system's IP is visible.

Comment: Indeed! Well the user calls THE SOAP, meaning the PHP file is getting called by the SOAP. So my question is, is there a possibility to pass the IP along with the other attributes without asking the user to send his ip? Can i somehow read it in the xml file? i guess not, right?

This is why i am asking for a workarround. I have been searching since days but cant find a propper solution.

I would be so happy if someone has a solution!